# Accumulative sum in every page Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, sum

I am developing a reporting in SSRS, I need display an initial balance and final balance for every page and get this final balance as inicial balance for the next page.

for example

**Page 1**

initial : 0

Transactions: 200

final : 200

**Page 2**

Initial : 200

Transactions : 150

final : 350

I have find how to get the sum for every page, but I need an accumulative sum like the example above

If someone have a suggest how to do that, I will appreciate.

Thanks

Jose Fuentes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in the header and footer of a page.

Assuming you have a dataset called `myDataset` and the column with your values in is called 'Amounts'...

Add a new column to your report with the Expression set to

```
=RunningValue(Fields!Amounts.Value, Sum, "myDataset")
```

Let's name this cell 'Balance' for ease of reference (but you can leave it as the default TextBox99 or whatever...)

Add a page header and footer to the report.

In the header add a text box and set it's expression to be

```
=FIRST(ReportItems!Balance.Value)
```

Add a text box to the footer and set its expression to be

```
=LAST(ReportItems!Balance.Value)
```

Check the resluts look correct then hide the `Balance` column if required.

That's it.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for the help, it works for the final balance, for the initial I have the small problem that the function adds the value of the first row, but your suggestion helped me find the solution, Regards